# When to use .count() and .value_counts() in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning pandas. I'm not sure when to use the `.count()` function and when to use `.value_counts()`.

Answer (score 4):

count() is used to count the number of non-NA/null observations across the given axis. It works with non-floating type data as well.

Now as an example create a dataframe df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10, 8, 12, None, 5, 3],  
                   "B":[-1, None, 6, 4, None, 3], 
                   "C":["Shreyas", "Aman", "Apoorv", np.nan, "Kunal", "Ayush"]})
```

Find the count of non-NA value across the row axis.

```
df.count(axis = 0)
```

Output:

```
A    5
B    4
C    5
dtype: int64
```

Find the number of non-NA/null value across the column.

```
df.count(axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    2
2    3
3    1
4    2
5    3
dtype: int64
```

value_counts() function returns Series containing counts of unique values. The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element. Excludes NA values by default.

So for the example shown below

```
s = pd.Series([3, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan]) 
s.value_counts()
```

The output would be:

```
3.0    2
4.0    1
2.0    1
1.0    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

`value_counts()` aggregates the data and counts each unique value. You can achieve the same by using `groupby` which is a more broad function to aggregate data in pandas.

`count()` simply returns the number of non NaN/Null values in column (series) you apply it on.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F'],
                   'Value':[10, 20, 15, 5, 35, 20, 10, 25]})

print(df)
  Id  Value
0  A     10
1  B     20
2  B     15
3  C      5
4  D     35
5  E     20
6  F     10
7  F     25

# Value counts
df['Id'].value_counts()
F    2
B    2
C    1
A    1
D    1
E    1
Name: Id, dtype: int64

# Same operation but with groupby
df.groupby('Id')['Id'].count()
Id
A    1
B    2
C    1
D    1
E    1
F    2
Name: Id, dtype: int64

# Count()
df['Id'].count()
8
```

**Example** with `NaN` values and `count`:

```
print(df)
    Id  Value
0    A     10
1    B     20
2    B     15
3  NaN      5
4    D     35
5    E     20
6    F     10
7    F     25

df['Id'].count()
7
```

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that the count function on a Series returns the number of non NA/null observations in the Series (as per the documentation)

Answer (score 1):

`count()` returns the total number of non-null values in the series.

`value_counts()` returns a series of the number of times *each unique non-null value* appears, sorted from most to least frequent.

As usual, an example is the best way to convey this:

```
ser = pd.Series(list('aaaabbbccdef'))
ser

>
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     b
5     b
6     b
7     c
8     c
9     d
10    e
11    f
dtype: object

ser.count()
>
12

ser.value_counts()
>
a    4
b    3
c    2
f    1
d    1
e    1
dtype: int64
```

Note that a dataframe has the `count()` method, which returns a series of the `count()` (scalar) value for each column in the df. However, a dataframe has no `value_counts()` method.