# Regarding counting of duplicate values in data

Tags: python, database, dataframe, duplicates, analysis

How to get all the duplicate values of one specific column in dataframe?
I want to only check values on one column but it's getting output with table or data.
I want to count the number the times each value is repeated

Comment: You can do this with value_counts which gives you a count of each value https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use .count() and .value\_counts() in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494028/when-to-use-count-and-value-counts-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Use `df['column'].value_counts()`.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct , and further can be converted to dict

```
df["col1"].value_counts().to_dict()
```